# YouTube plays "elevator music"

Tags: youtube

When I start to watch any YouTube video, YouTube starts to play a random background music over the YT page. If I pause the video, the music continues to play. The only way I can make it stop is to close down the browser. I'm using Crome and have YouTube Premium (3 month free trial).

Have anyone had a similar problem? And how did you fix it?

It makes YouTube unusable.

Answer (score 0):

You may have background play turned on for YouTube Music. (YouTube Music Premium is included with YouTube Premium.) Try disabling it by following these steps:

- Select **Menu**
- Select **Settings**
- Select **Background Play**
- Select **Off**

*Source:* https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6308116?hl=en

Comment: "Background Play is available on YouTube mobile apps…" This doesn't include Chrome. (With background play, you'd also know where the music was coming from, since it would be either the app you're currently in or YT.)